# KafkaConsumer not polling all messages

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a code similar to the one below:

```
KafkaConsumer<Long, String> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
partitions = Collections.singletonList(new TopicPartition(topic, partition));
kafkaConsumer.assign(partitions);
kafkaConsumer.seekToBeginning(List.of(partition));

ConsumerRecords<Long, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(pollDuration));
```

While running the code, I am not able to get all the messages in this particular topic.
For example, if I have 24 records in this partition, I am able to get only 20 records.

This issue does not happen always. When we make Kafka (wurstmeister/kafka:1.1.0) up using docker in the same machine in which my application runs, I am able to get all records from that particular partition.

But when I make the same docker-compose up in another machine and connect to it, this issue happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing `fetch.min.bytes` and, possibly `fetch.max.wait.ms` too.

> `fetch.min.bytes`
> The minimum amount of data the server should return for a fetch request. If insufficient data is available the request will wait for that much data to accumulate before answering the request. The default setting of 1 byte means that fetch requests are answered as soon as a single byte of data is available or the fetch request times out waiting for data to arrive. Setting this to something greater than 1 will cause the server to wait for larger amounts of data to accumulate which can improve server throughput a bit at the cost of some additional latency.
>
> `fetch.max.wait.ms`
> The maximum amount of time the server will block before answering the fetch request if there isn't sufficient data to immediately satisfy the requirement given by fetch.min.bytes.

Comment: I tried setting the above mentioned values and after that added few messages into the topic. But after 2 days, when I checked, the problem still exists. Please note that i am using default values for log retention and offset retention

Comment: `>the problem still exists` What "problem"? There is no guarantee that all records in a topic/partition will be returned on a poll. You need to keep polling.

Comment: Sorry for replying late. But do you mean to say it is ok to keep polling in a loop till we get all the messages from the topic?